# Test if NSString ends with whitespace or newline character?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

How do I test if the last character of an `NSString` is a whitespace or newline character.

I could do `[[NSCharacter whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet] characterIsMember:lastChar]`. But, how do I get the last character of an `NSString`?

Or, should I just use `- [NSString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:options:]` with a reverse search?

Answer (score 22):

You're on the right track. The following shows how you can retrieve the last character in a string; you can then check if it's a member of the `whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet` as you suggested.

```
unichar last = [myString characterAtIndex:[myString length] - 1];
if ([[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet] characterIsMember:last]) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: you are 2 mins. faster than me.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you can use `length` on an `NSString` object to get its length and then use:

```
- (unichar)characterAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

with `index` as `length - 1`. Now you have the last character which can be compared with `[NSCharacter whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
@implementation NSString (Additions)

- (BOOL)endsInWhitespaceOrNewlineCharacter {
    NSUInteger stringLength = [self length];
    if (stringLength == 0) {
        return NO;
    }
    unichar lastChar = [self characterAtIndex:stringLength-1];
    return [[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet] characterIsMember:lastChar];
}

@end
```